# Count frequency of certain number from a single row including all columns in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Dataframe looks like :

> ```
> id  a   b   c   d   e   f
> 1   0  -1  -1   1   0  -1
> 2  -1   1   0  -1  -1  -1
> ```

If I pass 1 as id, I should be able to calculate the occurences of -1 in that row i.e. the count should be 3.

Comment: `(df.loc[1] == -1).sum()` or `df.loc[1].value_counts()[-1]`

Comment: @AChampion Thankyou, I previously used sum() and that causes problem if I want to calculate other digits like 2, 5 etc. This method is working for my problem. Actually I wanted to calculate occurrences of -1 in a particular row when I pass value of 'a' not the id. `print(data.loc[data['website_id'] == input].squeeze().value_counts()[-1])` and I came with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
print (((df.loc[1] == -1).sum()) * -1)
```

Comment: Surely, this returns `-3`, there's no need to multiple by `-1`. You are just `sum`ing the `True` values.

Comment: THanks for the help, but this solution will only work on 1 and -1. If there are other numbers, it will simply add them, not calculate the occurrences.